# How to send Push Notifications at Specific times listed in a Django Model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, push-notification, django-push-notifications

I am looking to use my django rest framework project along with django push notifications to send notifications to iOS users. I want these notifications to be sent at times specified in my django models. What would be the best way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Depending on the desired exactitude, you could use a Celery background task running every few minutes checking which notifications need to be sent

Comment: You didn't specify where you deploying, but you can also create a custom management command with a scheduler, for example in Heroku you install the add-on scheduler, and run the command there.

Comment: @yovelcohen i have an aws ec2 server running with my drf project on it is there any way I could have a scheduler on that server as well?

Comment: haven't deployed with ec2, but I'm sure you do, just look it up